# It is possible to copy home folder to NTFS and keep permissions?

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I use grsync to copy my home folder to an external drive. This however doesn't keep permissions of the files.

Is there a way to copy home folder to an NTFS partition (to be readable and editable on Windows) without losing file permissions?

Comment: Please do not confuse "backup" with making a copy. A backup is SOLELY to save a copy of your data and nothing else.

Comment: @ToDo : for change permission on NTFS, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Answer (score 0):

As long as the drive is connected to a Linux system, the Linux file permissions and ownership cannot be transferred to the NTFS file system. If the NTFS drive is hooked up to a Windows system and accessed over the network by e.g. the SMB protocol, then you can, to a certain extent, retain file permissions and ownership.